# Steam not installing - unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, steam

I can't seem to install steam. Everything in the Software Center seems to run smoothly, but then this happens. (Excuse my possibly obvious question, I installed Ubuntu about 30 minutes ago with not much prior knowledge :/)
Terminal opens up asking for my password (below)

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for pixelspark:
```

When I put in my password, this happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-    0ubuntu0.6)
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is  not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going  to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be    caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

Then I press enter, which makes an error message pop up saying that I don't have libc.so.6 and Steam may not run. When I click OK, the message goes away and nothing else happens. Any help?

(again, excuse my foolishness and possibly obvious question)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention the [AMDGPU](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) driver installed nicely and took care of those unmet dependencies and no need to preload libraries.
Ubuntu and AMD both may abide yet.

> Hardware Details:
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, >Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E] >[1002:683f] Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology >Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E] [174b:e213]
> Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
> Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
>
> yakkety "Linux OGREOGRE 4.8.0-37-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP"